# Not showing the nearby cast DeviceSelection screen in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-cast, xcode11, google-cast-sdk

In my app when I tap on the cast button I only able to see the nearby device option. On clicking the nearby device selection options a screen with all the nearby cast devices should appear. In my case, it's not appearing which should come from the google-cast-sdk itself. I am using
pod 'google-cast-sdk', '>=4.4.4'. I am sharing my code so that It would be easy to understand where is the issue coming from.

```
func setupCastButton() {
    var castButton: GCKUICastButton! = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    castButton.tintColor = .darkGray

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(castDeviceDidChange(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.gckCastStateDidChange,
                                           object: GCKCastContext.sharedInstance())
}

/// Keep track of the Cast state changes
@objc func castDeviceDidChange(notification _: Notification) {


    print("castDeviceDidChange\(GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().castState.rawValue)")

    if GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().castState != GCKCastState.noDevicesAvailable {
        // Display the instructions for how to use Google Cast on the first app use.
        GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().presentCastInstructionsViewControllerOnce(with: castButton)
    }
}






@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    initialise()


    return true
}



let receiverAppID = kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID// or "receiverAppID"

let debugLoggingEnabled = true

private var sessionManager: GCKSessionManager!


private override init() {} // To restrict multiple instance creation, as singleton deals with only one instance.


/// initialise chromecast setup
public func initialise() {
    setupDiscoveryCriteria()
    setUpSessionManager()

    // Enable logger.
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

/// creates google cast discovery criteria
private func setupDiscoveryCriteria() {
    let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: receiverAppID)
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
}


/// creates the GCKSessionManager
private func setUpSessionManager() {
    sessionManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager
    sessionManager.add(self)
}
```

I am getting something below logs every time.

```
 [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <UITableView: 0x1080e1200; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 9992; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2827b30c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x28296c220>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 73}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <GCKUIDeviceConnectionViewController: 0x1080b1c00>>
2019-10-23 14:23:08.501527+0530  [Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
2019-10-23 14:23:08.501640+0530  
[Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
2019-10-23 14:23:09.022438+0530 [Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
2019-10-23 14:23:09.022554+0530 [Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
2019-10-23 14:23:11.857338+0530 [Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
2019-10-23 14:23:11.857543+0530 [Assert] button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateDisabled and UIControlStateFocused. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
castDeviceDidChange2
2019-10-23 14:23:11.879911+0530 Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UIViewController: 0x111259f40>.
```

Comment: Can we use the default kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID or do we need newly generated ReceiverApplicationID for the unpublished application? Please let me know.

Comment: Also, I have checked with google provided CastVideos-swift application which is continuously giving the below error:

Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UIViewController: 0x103887030>.

Can anyone please help me what best could be done?

Comment: Make sure your devices are on same wifi network. If guest mode is available that means you have some cast devices nearby but not on the same network.

Comment: My devices are in the same network.

Comment: @TapashMollick, were you able to show app screen/view rather than playing the video? I meant is it possible with the current iOS Cast SDK? I see media play everywhere.  No way to mirror (app screen to external TV) , please share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking on iOS 14.0 devices, Apple have introduced new local network permission that needs to be prompted to user and if the permission is granted devices in the local network can be discoverable otherwise you can't see the devices even if they are connected to same wifi network.

I guess this permission is not handled in your iOS app.

You have to follow below link on how to enable this in the iOS sender app that used google cast sdk.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/permissions_and_discovery